# Add a specific column values at the end of row in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have Dataframe df as shown below: For every row if first found column value is None, that should be replaced by column 2 value from dataframe.

```
 ID     1           2      col0      col1      col2      col3     col4     col5 col6
0 A1    ABC         RED     10        20       None     None     None      None None
1 B1    ABC         ORANGE  40        None     None     None     None      None None
2 C1    ABC         WHITE   50        34        35       57       78         98 None
3 D1    ABC         BLUE    20        None     None     None      None     None None
```

I Want output:

```
ID       1          col0      col1      col2     col3     col4     col5   col6
0 A1    ABC        10        20       RED
1 B1    ABC        40        ORANGE
2 C1    ABC        50        34        35       57       78         98  WHITE
3 D1    ABC        20        BLUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is forward filling non missing values with limit parameter, test non missing values and chain with test missing values - so mask match only `None`s for append values from column `2` by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), last replace `None`s by empty strings by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
m = df.ffill(axis=1, limit=1).notna() & df.isna()

df = df.mask(m, df.pop(2), axis=0).fillna('')
print (df)
   ID    1  col0    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5   col6
0  A1  ABC    10      20  RED                      
1  B1  ABC    40  ORANGE                           
2  C1  ABC    50      34   35   57   78   98  WHITE
3  D1  ABC    20    BLUE
```

Comment: this works fine for given condition. What if I have values till col6 and column 2 values needs to be put after col6 for ex.                                                                                                    ID     1           2      col0      col1      col2      col3     col4     col5 col6
0     C1    ABC       WHITE   50        34        35       57       78         98 99

Comment: @Rashmi - Then create helper new column before my solution like `df = df.assign(new=None)`

Comment: thanks! and If I have more columns like col 2 which I need to move

Comment: @Rashmi - Unfortunately then this solution cannot be used, need someting else, the best is post new question.